# mandel-number formula "string does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Tags: c#

(I'm a beginner to both programming and this website. In advance: I appologize if I make any mistakes in terms of using this website the wrong way.)

(using C#)

I'm trying to write a method to calculate mandel-numbers (with the intent of using the method in another program) but I've got an error message saying:

" Error 1   'string' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments  "

Before this it was "not all code paths return a value", but I think I fixed that with convert.tostring. This error however, is new to me.

I have no idea what this means, could anyone explain what the problem is?

using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1{

```
public class formule
{
    static int Main()
{    
        double f = new double();
        double x = new double();
        double y = new double();
        double a = new double();
        double b = new double();
        int n = new int();
        double max = new double();
        double schaal = new double();
        double afstand = new double();

        x = 0.5;
        y = 0.8;
        n = 0;
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        max = 100;
        //schaal = invoer 4
        afstand = 0;

        while (afstand <= 2 || n < max)
        {

            afstand = Math.Sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
            n++;
            a = (a * a - b * b + x);
            b = (2 * a * b + y);


        }
        string mandelgetal;
        mandelgetal = new string();
        mandelgetal = Convert.ToString(n);

        Console.WriteLine(mandelgetal);
        Console.ReadLine();
}






    }

}
```

Comment: Try: string mandelgetal = n.ToString();

Comment: `"Before this it was "not all code paths return a value", but I think I fixed that with convert.tostring"` ...... no.

Comment: `double` and `int` are value types, you don't need to use `new` with those.

Comment: In addition to the answers there is a logic error in your code. You need to store the old value of `a` since you use it when calculating `b`. If you don't do this the Mandelbrot fractal will look skewed. `a_tmp = a; a = a_tmp * a_tmp - b * b + x; b = 2 * a_tmp * b + y;`

Answer (score 2):

It means *'string' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments*

If you want an empty string initialize your variable with `string.Empty` or assign it to *null* to avoid uninitialized variable errors.

In addition to that you can see all the `public` constructors of `String` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string(v=vs.110).aspx) and you will notice that there is no *parameterless* constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem on this line (well, some other problems, but the blocking one) is

```
mandelgetal = new string();
```

as there's no ctor without argument for string (and here, you have nothing between your parenthesis).

So you could just do

```
var mandelgetal = string.Empty;
```

or

```
var mandeldetal = Convert.ToString(n);
```

but it would really be easier to remove these lines :

```
string mandelgetal;
mandelgetal = new string();
mandelgetal = Convert.ToString(n);
```

and just do

```
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

as `Console.WriteLine` can take an int as argument.

**EDIT**

I would rewrite all that with (assuming your algo is correct)

```
const double X = 0.5;
const double Y = 0.8;
const double Max = 100;

int n = 0;
double afstand = 0;
double a = 0;
double b = 0;

while (afstand <= 2 || n < Max) {

        afstand = Math.Sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
        n++;
        a = (a * a - b * b + X);
        b = (2 * a * b + Y);
}

Console.WriteLine(n);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: As you suspect the algoritm isn't 100% correct. The old value of `a` needs to be stored since it is used in updating both `a` and `b`. If not used properly the Mandelbrot fractal will look skewed.

Answer (score 0):

You are producing a lot of unnecessary code. Have a look below what is *necessary*:

```
public class formule
  {
    static void Main()
    {    
        double f;
        double x = 0.5;
        double y = 0.8;
        double a;
        double b;
        int n;
        double max = 100.0;
        double schaal;
        double afstand;

        while (afstand <= 2 || n < max)
        {
            afstand = Math.Sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
            n++;
            a = (a * a - b * b + x);
            b = (2 * a * b + y);
        }

        string mandelgetal = n.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(mandelgetal);
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
  }
```

Everything else is just a potential for errors. In your case, you called a constructor that does not exist. If you don't know what a constructor is yet, don't use them, keep it simple like above and continue with the exercises, the chapter will come sooner or later.

Comment: In addition to the problems you pointed out there is a logical error in the calculation. The old value of `a` needs to be stored since it's used in calculating the new value of both `a` and `b`. If not done properly the Mandelbrot fractal will look skewed.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus They were originally set to zero. As zero already is the default value, that would not add anything of value.

Comment: It seems like the error with the constructor method can be fixed.
However, I still can't find out why the compiler claims that not all code paths return a value.

This has to have to do with the 'While' section right? but how can that part not have an outcome when I added n<max in combination with n++?

That way, if "afstand <= 2" is never (not) met the other condition (n<max) will provide an outcome right?

Comment: @A.R.Lifmann You need to return a value if your Main returns `int`. It's common in C# to return `void`, so you don't need to bother with a return value for Main.